# Is there a difference between .Parameter<int[]> and .CollectionParameter<int> for Odata v4 action parameters?

Tags: c#, odata, odata-v4

I know that in my question .CollectionParameter is the more correct way to do it. But both work without issue. I've searched for a difference between them and I can't find anything. All I've found is that the documentation says to use CollectionParamter for enumerable types. It doesn't say why to do that vs the other. Can anyone explain the difference between them?